# Minipage inside MetaPost label within GMP - what is wrong?

Tags: beamer, minipage, metapost

Any clues please??

The following MWE will not compile.
Line where **minipage** environment was used seems to be the offensor. With that left out compiling is OK.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex, everymp=input metaobj; input boxes;
input rboxes;  input latexmp;]{gmp} 
\usempxclass{article}

\usetheme{Montpellier} \title{Something} \date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}


\begin{frame} \frametitle{Frame 1} \begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[name=networkA]

numeric d; d:= 100;

boxit.mx(btex M U X etex rotated -90);


mx.c = origin;

drawboxed(mx);

boxit.dmx("DMX"); dmx.dy=.2d; dmx.c = mx.e + (d,0); drawboxed(dmx);

drawarrow mx.e--dmx.w;

circleit.tx("Tx"); circleit.rx("Rx");

tx.c = mx.c -.5d*dir(0) +.2d*dir(90); drawboxed(tx);

rx.c = dmx.c +.5d*dir(0) +.2d*dir(90); drawboxed(rx);

\end{mpost} \centering\usempost{networkA} \end{figure} \end{frame}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Frame 2} \begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[name=networkB]

numeric d; d:= 100;

boxit.mx(\btex \begin{minipage}[t]{1em}M U X\end{minipage} etex); mx.c
= origin; drawboxed(mx);

boxit.dmx("DMX"); dmx.dy=.2d; dmx.c = mx.e + (d,0); drawboxed(dmx);

drawarrow mx.e--dmx.w;

circleit.tx("Tx"); circleit.rx("Rx");

tx.c = mx.c -.5d*dir(0) +.2d*dir(90); drawboxed(tx);

rx.c = dmx.c +.5d*dir(0) +.2d*dir(90); drawboxed(rx);

\end{mpost} \centering\usempost{networkB} \end{figure} \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround is simple:

```
boxit.mx(\btex {\begin{minipage}[t]{1em}M U X\end{minipage}} etex);
```

The documentation tells that the braces around environments is necessary when `mpost` is used as the argument to a command, which is always the case with `beamer`.